# How many max_connections should I have?

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

We run a monolith *Spring Boot* application which is set up as multi-tenant, so every customer has their own app service and database (around 30-40 of them) but they still run on the same **PostreSQL** server. We previously had problems with not having enough space for connections in our database because our connection pooler (**HikariCP**) was incorrectly set up, which caused chaos between the environments when someone would get 15 idle connections while someone didn't have any at all and couldn't connect to the database, which caused crash of the application.

Our fix was to change our **max_connections** from 150 to 350, and while it helped with crashes I'm unsure if it's the right way. After doing some research it seems like just doing a higher number on **max_connections** isn't the smartest way due to performance issues. Today in our application we set minimum pool size to 5 and max to 10, but I'm wondering if it's an overkill and we should go down to min 2 max 5 as well as lowering our max_connections back to around 150-200. Or is it safe to keep our **max_connections** number as it is? In that case, what hardware is recommended for that? Today we're running on **1 vCPU**, **3.5gb RAM** but we're planning on upgrading. What is the most optimal in our case? What to do when the number of our databases (customers) increases? Do we upgrade our **max_connections** to whatever is needed or set up a new **PostgreSQL** server? Thank you in advance

Comment: As long as everything runs smoothly, those value do not mean much here. If your DB server can handle that many connection, there is no point in changing. That being said, unused resources are not good so it would be nice to know how many connections are needed for your app and reduce it to that level.

Comment: Isn't it contradictory that it is a monolith, yet each customer has their own app service?

Comment: @grekier I will consider it, thank you for your answer

Comment: @jjanes It is indeed very impractical, the reason it's done this way is because they connect to different databases as well as different identification provider realms. We are looking into turning it into single tenant application instead, which should have been done since the start of the project

Answer (score 0):

350 connections for 3.5GB RAM is certainly a lot, that is only 10MB per backend.  This is not *guaranteed* to cause swapping/paging problems, but it wouldn't be surprising at all if it did.  I would try lowering the max connection pool size.    Doing that might not cause any problems at all, and if it does they are likely to be more manageable.  Having your database server swapping to death is the worst. Your monitoring stops working. Your ability to make changes goes away because the terminal itself stops responding in a reasonable timeframe.